# solution verification: $y'''-3y'+2y=24e^{t}$ with laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, laplace-transform

I tried to solve this ode, but the solution seems to be very strange.

solve: $y'''-3y'+2y=24e^{t}$ given that $y''(0)=y'(0)=y(0)=0$.

$s^{3}Ly-3sLy+2Ly=\frac{24}{s-1}\\Ly(s^{3}-3s+2)=\frac{24}{s-1}\\Ly=\frac{24}{(s-1)^{3}(s+2)}$

partial fractions:
$\frac{24}{(s-1)^{3}(s+2)}=\frac{a}{s-1}+\frac{b}{(s-1)^{2}}+\frac{c}{(s-1)^{3}}+\frac{\text{d}}{s+2}$
so:
$\frac{24}{(s-1)^{3}(s+2)}=\frac{8/9}{s-1}+\frac{-8/3}{(s-1)^{2}}+\frac{8}{(s-1)^{3}}+\frac{\text{-8/9}}{s+2}$
meaning:
$y=\frac{8}{9}e^{t}-\frac{8}{3}te^{t}+8t^{2}e^{t}-\frac{8}{9}e^{-2t}$

**edit found a mistake**:
$\frac{24}{(s-1)^{2}(s+2)}=\frac{a}{s-1}+\frac{b}{(s-1)^{2}}+\frac{\text{d}}{s+2}\\24=a(s+2)(s-1)+b(s+2)+d(s-1)^{2}\\24=a(-2+s+s^{2})+b(s+2)+d(1-2s+s^{2})\\24=-2a+2b+d\\0=a+b-2d\\0=a+d$

therefore:
$\frac{24}{(s-1)^{2}(s+2)}=\frac{-8/3}{s-1}+\frac{8}{(s-1)^{2}}+\frac{\text{8/3}}{s+2}\\y=-\frac{8}{3}e^{t}+8te^{t}+8t^{2}e^{t}+\frac{8}{3}e^{-2t}$

Comment: @Moo try to fix, can you have a look?

Comment: It is close - some simple issue - you should get $$y(t) = 4 e^t t^2-\frac{8 e^t t}{3}-\frac{8 e^{-2 t}}{9}+\frac{8 e^t}{9}$$

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the inverse transform of $\frac1{(s-1)^3}$ in the original attempt, like a missing factor $\frac1{2!}$.